# Replace Function not giving expected output in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to replace the tab with the expected output as `"129hello3 78 0"`.Its showing same output after running the below mentioned lines of code.
I have given tab space between `"129"` and `"3"` and rest others are spaces

```
a="129  3 78 0"
b=a.replace('\t+','hello')
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tab in `a="129  3 78 0"`, but rather two spaces. For example, copy and paste tab from the text editor to ensure that the right character is in string `a`.
Here is the example:

```
a="129  3 78 0"
b=a.replace('   ','hello')
print(b)

a="129  3 78 0"
b=a.replace('\t','hello')
print(b)
```

The output is

```
129hello3 78 0
129hello3 78 0
```

In order to get this result, please open the editor of your choice (I am using Notepad here) paste the code there, and make sure that you have tab in required spaces (circled in red):
[image]

then copy the code from there and insert intoonline compiler of your choice ( I used https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/). Click `Run`
[image]

Comment: But even if its not tab and i give a.replace('\s+','hello') to replace the spaces,its still reflecting the original string.There is no space getting replaced.When i just use as a.replace(' ','hello').It works in that case

Comment: Added the code with a step by step instruction.

Comment: Thank you so much))I got it.Its the respective tab size and space size which can vary from editor to editor due to which it was not working previously.

Comment: @Ashish34630 Please accept as it as a solution if it helped you to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using replace instead of regex.

```
import re
a="129  3 78 0"
b=re.sub('[\t]+','hello', a)
print(b)

Or if you need replace:
a="129  3 78 0"
b=a.replace('\t','hello')
print(b)
```